# Is there any way to upload more than 10 MB file from Salesforce using HTTP Request to Dropbox?

Tags: salesforce, dropbox-api, apex-code

This below code is working perfect with 10 MB but when I try to upload more than 20MB files then it throws an error.

```
private string TOKEN = 'access_token_of_dropbox_app';
string folderPathWithFileName;
for(ContentVersion contentVersionRec : [SELECT PathOnClient, VersionData 
                                        FROM contentversion
                                        WHERE contentdocumentId IN : contentDocumentIdSet]){
    folderPathWithFileName = '/Root/'+PathOnClient;//PathOnClient contains file name with extension 
    //like imagefile.png
    system.debug('###folderPathWithFileName=>'+folderPathWithFileName);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
    httpReq.setEndpoint('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
    httpReq.setMethod('POST');
    httpReq.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + TOKEN);
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
    httpReq.setHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg','{"path":"'+folderPath+'","mode":{".tag":"add"}}');
    httpReq.setBodyAsBlob(contentVersionRec.VersionData);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpReq);
    System.debug('res###' + httpResponse);
    System.debug('res.getBody()###'+httpResponse.getBody());
    if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        System.debug('##Congratulations File Uploaded successfully :) =>'+httpResponse.getBody());
    }else{
        //Handle code here when file not uploaded. 
    }
}
```

When I try to upload 20 MB File it throws an error :

> System.CalloutException: Exceeded max size limit of 12000000 with request size 12001280

This above code runs in queueable(Async) apex and that queueable apex fires from the trigger. so I am able to upload 10 MB file successfully. I am also aware of limitations of heap size of 12 MB in ASYNC apex.
But want to know is there way to upload the file from salesforce to dropbox more than 10 MB. I want to upload max 100 MB file from the apex HTTP request to dropbox.

Note: dropbox API also allows us to upload data in chunk means we can send data in chunks using apex HTTP request to dropbox. But the challenge is while making the chunks first we need to convert blob data to string or base64 to make multiple chunks. it will work fine with 7-8 MB but when we have 20 MB more then it will also throw heap size error while converting blob to string or base64.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! Try also asking on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

See if you can use the dropbox plugin https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000prqLEAQ. It might be coming with some Apex or JavaScript built-ins you could call, you'd have to inspect the package for methods marked `global` and/or contact Dropbox directly.

Or have you considered another storage provider? There's built-in support for Google Drive, SharePoint, OneDrive & Box called [Files Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_files_connect.htm&type=5). This is bit cheesy and 5 years old but decent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG3m3zP00KQ

Failing that - not much you can do in pure apex, it's a hard limit. You might be able to pull it off by "downloading" the file to JavaScript, chunking it there and sending chunks either directly to Dropbox or via Apex service (if you want to keep the API key server-side).

You could reverse the flow. Can Dropbox pull documents or is it only push? If not - can you send a notification to another app (say hosted on Heroku), it'd login to SF (or you could pass current user's session id) and it'd pull the document via SF standard API, then send it up. You'd be paying for bandwidth I imagine but it could work good enough, especially if you'd put this app as a "canvas" so it integrates nicely with rest of Salesforce, current user would be silently logged in...

Comment: As for having Dropbox "pull", instead of uploading to it, Dropbox does offer [the /2/files/save_url endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url) which may work here, if you can get a URL to the file.

Comment: @Greg the file has to be publicly visible, right? Tricky. You can expose files in SF but I have a feeling these will be hidden behind login, which means Dropbox would have to put `Authorization Bearer <sf session id goes here>` or present a JWT token or some other OAuth2 tricks... Hm. Again, if you'd have intermediary server you could pull file, expose it to dropbox and delete after few minutes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it needs to be publicly accessible. Dropbox doesn't offer a way to add headers or credentials.

Comment: Thanks, Eyescream and Greg for help. Dropbox save_url works for me. I created content distribution records first then I am passing ContentDistribution.ContentDownloadUrl to upload to save_url endpoint and after uploading all files I am deleting content distribution records.
Again thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... Thats the issue we also struggling. The answer to overcome such limitations is based on the architecture. If you are using a LWC or AURA component to upload/download files to  dropbox api you can utilize Javascript instead of APEX. In taht case you have to struggle with CSP and CORS Limitations and issues.

Javascript is executed on client-side within the browser and the browser limitations of RAM usage. I think in almost every case the client resources are much bigger than 12 MB of RAM.

I dont know any streaming concept within APEX, so any content must fit into the Heap Size Limit.

Once Salesforce enables Evergreen you might overcome this limits using Evergreen, which is not running within the Salesforce platform but within the heroku platform (i guess). this platform delivers ressources on demand and should have higher limitations.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/introducing-salesforce-evergreen